# Print line changes (with '\r') on new lines instead of updating the line

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

As per my understanding, many programs *animate* their command line output (`stdout` or `stderr`) with the `\r` return carriage. For example, `apt-get update` will update the package download percentage, or `docker-compose up` will animate a list of containers that are updating and/or starting up. Of course there are thousands of other examples.

[image]

I need the following: for each line update, actually rewrite this line on a new line. So let's take the example gif displayed above, I want something like:

```
buntu-22.04.2-deskt   0%[                    ]  25,59M  11,5MB/s               
untu-22.04.2-deskto   0%[>                   ]  30,68M  11,5MB/s               
ntu-22.04.2-desktop   0%[>                   ]  35,21M  11,5MB/s       
tu-22.04.2-desktop-   0%[=>                  ]  40,47M  11,5MB/s       
...
```

How can I do this? Note that I wish it would work for any program that uses this functionality.

I tried:
`command | tr '\r' '\n'` but this didn't work.

Comment: Those programs are probably not using `\r` for that but instead something like ncurses. Try passing it a command line argument that outputs progress in a different way

Comment: You can only use `\r` for single line effects. If you want to do the same for multiline, you will need to use a more complex package. Curses is one.

Comment: Your `tr` command is replacing `\r` with `\n` - you probably intended this to be the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Curses will just use whatever the terminal support. With Linux and other Unix like systems, it will use ANSI sequences.

For instance, try `printf "\033[17;62H"` at the command line. You will find that the cursor will go to line 17, column 62.

If you look at the wikipedia entry, [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and scroll down to `CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) sequences`, you will see what you need.

I recommend you look at the entire page, since there is an awful lot you can do, with just the right sequences of characters.